# ExtJS4 - Extending different components from a single base class

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a web app for which I am using ExtJS 4.2.  This application has a bunch of different components - a panel that displays some data, another panel that displays some other data, a grid, a chart, etc, etc.

It's required that each component has at minimum a specific set of functions and properties.  So I'd like to define a 'component' class that I can extend everything else from.  For example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.BaseComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myapp-basecomponent',

    prop1: true,
    prop2: 17,

    func1: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
});
```

Then I would extend every individual component in my app from that base component class.  The problem is that if I define the base component as extending 'Ext.panel.Panel', I can only extend other panels from it.  I can't extend a grid, tree, etc, etc from it.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?  Or am I approaching this the wrong way?  Maybe I should just nest everything that's not a panel (grid, chart, etc) in a panel so they can all extend from BaseComponent?  Advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to augment the base component class, you could always just provide an override that adds them:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.AugmentComponent', {
    override: 'Ext.Component',

    a: 1,
    b: 2,

    fn1: function() {
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't really want to do that... don't need those properties and functions for every little component in my app.

Comment: If you don't call them, what does it matter?

Comment: Just seems kinda wrong to me... there wouldn't be any ill effects from having every single button, text field, etc inherit a bunch of useless properties and functions?

Comment: Nope, they will go on the prototype.

Comment: The only other reasonable way to do it would be to create your own extensions for each class (component, container, panel, grid, chart) and then mixin your overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I ended up nesting my grid/chart/etc components in panels and then just extending Ext.panel.Panel.